# Drawing in a Canvas Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

When I load the page, the canvas loads and fills the background as white. But, when I click and drag in the canvas, it wont draw for me.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  canvas.height = 200;
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;

  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  let painting = false;

  function startPosition(e) {
    painting = true;
    draw(e);
  }

  function endPosition() {
    painting = false;
    ctx.beginPath();
  }

  function draw(e) {
    if (!painting) return;
    ctx.lineWidth = 7;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
  }

  //Event Listeners
  canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", startPosition);
  canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", endPosition);
  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);
})
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
```

Comment: I put your code in a snippet and it appears to work fine. Have you checked to see if your code has any errors in the console?

Comment: Weird, yeah, I see it is working here. But I don't get any errors in console when I try running it on the sever. It just refuses to draw. And when I right click and inspect the canvas, it goes straight to the canvas element